# Unique tags for different users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm currently investigating whether ActsAsTaggableOn is going to work for my needs. Specifically, I have an application where users can sign up and add people. They can tag people. However, I want to segregate the tags that one user creates from the tags that another user creates.

It seems like this would be a common requirement, so I'm a little surprised that it's not something obviously front and centre. Is this possible to do, and if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActsAsTaggableOn does not support the functionality you need.  I would recommend rolling your own tagging system and use ActsAsTaggableOn as an example of appropriate structures.

I would use a similar structure, except have the tag table also contain a user id that you could then use to scope tags to the current user.

Comment: Not the answer that I wanted, but the answer that I feared. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ActsAsTaggableOn` supports making a model `acts_as_tagger`, which allows you to retrieve the tags they've tagged (https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on). It seems like this is what you're talking about.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tagger
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :locations
end

@some_user.tag(@some_photo, :with => "paris, normandy", :on => :locations)
@some_user.owned_taggings
@some_user.owned_tags
@some_photo.locations_from(@some_user) # => ["paris", "normandy"]
@some_photo.owner_tags_on(@some_user, :locations) # => [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "paris">...]
@some_photo.owner_tags_on(nil, :locations) # => Ownerships equivalent to saying @some_photo.locations
@some_user.tag(@some_photo, :with => "paris, normandy", :on => :locations, :skip_save => true) #won't save @some_photo object
```

Particularly the line

```
@some_photo.locations_from(@some_user)...etc.
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think this would work in my situation, since a two users could have a tag with the same name, but with different attributes (since I'd be extending the Tag model to include things like a colour).